# How to capture fractures on metal frames? Camera setup with connection to pc to record pictures

Tags: equipment-recommendation, visible-light

I am looking for a simple setup of a decent inspection camera with an adjustable light. The light needs to come at an appropriate angle while the camera faces straight down on the metal frame. These fractures sometimes come up from screws getting tightened into the frame. It doesn't have to be a specific product but I am trying to find good options.

The other end of it needs to hook up in some way to a computer. I need to capture the image in a program, label it, and file it away for quality assurance. I know there are open standards for cameras and that may not be a big issue.

Comment: What is the finish/surface of those frames, how detailed picture you want of frames/cracks? Have you consider using some kind of defectoscope?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using a camera for for inspecting items in a production environment, rather than for the purpose of producing artistic, historical, or documentary photographs as the desired end result. (It's also a borderline request for product recommendations, which are specifically off-topic across the SE network.)

Comment: The described use fit perfectly in the "Documentary" purpose IMHO.

Comment: Do you move the camera to the metal frame or the metal frame to the camera? Otherwise high-end cameras (DSLR/"Mirroless", can be hooked to a PC from which you can 1) monitor what the camera sees and 2) change camera settings and 3) take pictures that are instalntly downloaded to the PC.

Comment: Amongst other things, size matters. Is it going to be a macro shot? Basically, it doesn't feel you need a technically spectacular set-up; perhaps a good webcam will do (they have an advantage of being _meant_ to work directly with the computer, and the interface is usually standard). It may be more important to set up oblique light correctly to reveal the texture.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It is usually a painted finish of varying colors, does not need to be super detailed, I have not considered a defectoscope but I will look it up

Comment: @Zeus It does need to be able to take close up shots, a webcam could work but I was looking for something a little more all in one if possible. I do need something with a light with oblique angle.

Comment: @xenoid The camera can be moved closer but does not need to move more than that. The fractures appear with light and don't need to be super detailed. A webcam could work but I was looking for something more all together if possible.

Comment: I have considered some microscope/cameras from amscope but on the cheaper end.

Comment: @Madborgnine, I see. And of course you understand that you will find correlation between price and quality...

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that we could recommend about anything as long as you dont give more information on what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A standard method to detects cracks and crazing is [dye penetrant testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed75mxtrj-4). To make tiny defects more clearly visible, [ultraviolet penetrant dyes](https://www.relinc.com/fluorescent-penetrant-inspection/) provide increased contrast.

You can can also increase contrast using optical filters on the camera lens, which is more effective than post-processing.